# Is possible have an alert box like javascript alert() on Django when you're deleting a post?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm working on a Django site and I would create a simpler way to delate a post better than going in a new HTML page every time. There is a way to have an alert box like JavaScript alert("text") and you can click OK to delete or the x to maintain the post and a way to not change the page? The code is:

**Urls.py**

```
code...
path('dashboard/delate/<slug:slug>', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name="delatepost"),
```

**Views.py**

```
code...
class PostDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "admin/deletepost.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("listpost")
```

**html**

```
code...
{% extends "admin/layout.html" %}
{% block title %}
    <title>Add Post</title>
{% endblock title %} 
{% block content %}

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<center>
    <div class="addpost">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h1>delete {{ post.title }}?</h1>
        <button>Remove</button>
        </div>
    </center>
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

(Right now there are no auth because I am testing on my computer)

Answer (score 2):

You can give the button a class and do this

Here I am assuming your button already deletes the post.

```
document.querySelector("some container selector").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("delete")) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

If not, use AJAX:

```
document.querySelector("some container selector").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.classList.contains("delete")) return 
  if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) return;

  const data = { postTitle: tgt.dataset.title };
  fetch('/delete', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  //Then with the data from the response in JSON...
  .then((data) => {
     console.log('Success:', data);
  })
  //Then with the error generated
  .catch((error) => {
     console.error('Error:', error);
  });
})
```

and have

```
<form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<center>
    <div class="addpost">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h1>delete {{ post.title }}?</h1>
        <button class="delete" data-title="{{ post.title }}">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </center>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for something NOT in delate.html, a way to escape the page and do the remove method in listpost.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this and have JavaScript submit the form. This will submit the form to Django and Django will perform the validation/redirect as well.

HTML

```
<form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<center>
    <div class="addpost">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h1>delete {{ post.title }}?</h1>
        <button id="removeButton">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </center>
</form>
```

JS

```
let removeButton = document.getElementById('removeButton');
removeButton.onclick = function() {
    let accepted = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
    if (accepted) {
        document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
    }
}
```

To do this without any page reloads, have a look into AJAX requests with Django and [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

Here's a couple resources:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

https://djangocentral.com/django-ajax-with-jquery/

Comment: What I posted is much more generic and attaches the event handler to the container of all buttons and then allows a click on any of the buttons to trigger the confirm. I believe it is a question of @LeonardoBasso not understanding what I proposed

Comment: You have shown how to create the confirm dialog @mplungjan but you never showed how to submit the form and have it delete as requested in the question.

Comment: Where is your AJAX then - I assumed OP already had the button working

Comment: I realise I've also misread the question, my bad. I've added some resources.

Comment: @DeanElliott So did I